# Wordpress plugin problem: can't get a text file in the same directory as the .php

Tags: php, wordpress, file-get-contents

Taken out of context:

```
<?php
$options=file_get_contents('options.txt');
?>
```

This isn't working. 'options.txt' is in the same directory as the plugin .php. What am I doing wrong? I thought that since the .php is being included from somewhere else, the path would be wrong, so I tried '/wp-content/plugins/myPlugin/options.txt'. But nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really use the appropriate WordPress [Plugin and Content Directories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories) function to obtain directory paths to ensure that your plugin will work on future versions of WordPress, etc.

Incidentally, you do realise that this file will technically be publically viewable via a URL? (Just mentioning it in case it contains anything even vaguely sensitive.)

Comment: Yes, of course. There's nothing sensitive. Just a few settings.

Comment: and btw, I finally did it liek this:$optionst=file_get_contents(plugins_url().'/my_plugin/options.txt');

Answer (score 1):

Use the path relative to the Wordpress root dir without a preceding slash:

```
wp-content/plugins/myPlugin/options.txt
```

Comment: However, there should be functions to get the directory of the plugin itself. Check the docs.

Comment: That did it. Damn I feel stupid. But yeah, I'll check the file functions.

Comment: Never feel stupid. Look into the future! The mistake you just made is solved. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend against using the native `file_get_contents()` method.  Not every server setup will allow this, so if you ever migrate your site or give the code to someone else, you might run into problems.

Instead, use the built-in [HTTP API](http://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API) that comes with WordPress.  Your specific example would become:

```
$options = wp_remote_retrieve_body( wp_remote_get( plugins_url() . '/my_plugin/options.txt' ) );
```

This will use the built-in API to GET the text file and then retrieve the body of the GET request (store the text file's contents in the `$options` variable.